# How to use change JSON structure using Compose action in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to change the JSON response I'm getting from a request I make using Logic apps like this:

[image]

This request will get the following response:

```
{
"invoiceID":1,
"formType":"invoice",
"amount":449,
"currency":"eur",
"description":"Invoice real estate",
"period":{"end":20122019,"start":20122020},
"owner":{
   "id":91434,
   "firstname":"John",
   "lastname":"Doe",
   "dateOfBirth":1121993,
   "phoneNumber":345435435,
   "countryOfBirth":"Nederland",
   "IBAN":"NL28 ABNA 743734g763474324"
},
"property":{
   "id":105,
   "type":"apartment",
   "address":"ghost lane 13",
   "ZIP":"7888 CK",
   "State\/Province":"Groningen",
   "country":"Nederland",
   "construction-year":15072009,
   "previousOwners":9
},
"previousProperties":[54,193,11,454,18]
}
```

Now I'm trying to compose the JSON of above to another json structure, for example to this:

```
{
"general": {
    "invoiceID": 12,
    "formType": "invoice",
    "amount": 449,
    "currency": "eur",
    "description": "Invoice real estate",
    "period": {
       "end": 20122019,
       "start": 20122020
    }
 }
 }
```

I tried using the Compose action for this:

[image]

Finally I return the response:

[image]]]

This setup does not work and I'm getting the following error:

*{"error":{"code":"NoResponse","message":"The server didbnt receive a answer of the upstream-server. The trace-id from the request is 08586376520125765844944852801CU36."}}*

When I remove the Compose action from the logic app designer, the flow does work but I'm getting the original JSON response.

**UPDATE**

I'm getting the following options for my compose configuration:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your pic, your Response body set the HTTP action body, you need set the `Compose` output, the below is my test result and i don't get your error. Maybe you could have a look. And looks like in your compose action, you set the value with wrong value, from your requirements, you need set them with `HTTP` get action output.

I test with a HTTP trigger.

[image]

And the below is my compose input:

```
"general": {
                        "amount": "@body('HTTP')['amount']",
                        "currency": "@body('HTTP')['currency']",
                        "description": "@body('HTTP')['description']",
                        "formType": "@body('HTTP')['formType']",
                        "invoiceID": "@body('HTTP')['invoiceID']",
                        "period": {
                            "end": "@body('HTTP')['period']['end']",
                            "start": "@body('HTTP')['period']['start']"
                        }
                    }
```

And here is the response what my postman get.

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Looks great but if I change the body of my response action to outputs I'm still getting the same error. I also tested this with postman.

Comment: The code you show at "And below is my compose output", how do I find this?

Comment: See update with the options I'm getting for compose actions.

Comment: The compose input I set it in the code view also you could set it with expression.

Comment: Maybe you could go to code view and test with my compose input.[code view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7G2z.png)

Comment: Awesome, it worked. But how can i acces body.amount for example? All I'm seeing is body.(look updated post)

Comment: What do you mean access  body.amount? You could check my example just with expression `body('HTTP')['amount']` to get the value. Cause not all dynamic content support to get directly.

Comment: I've dont that but why is it not in the list, see images under "update". I only have Body, Headers and Statuscode under my HTTP. The rest u use is under my "When HTTP request is received. and this does not work. In order words, how can i achieve what I just did with the code in the designer?

Comment: I think it's because the logic app couldn't know the body content before it does get action.

Comment: Also with the Expression, however they are same. So yes.